# MemoryMappedFile for IPC - How to decide how much space to allocate?

Tags: c#, ipc, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to use a C# [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for fast IPC; and not to map a persistent file.

I'm struggling in deciding how to choose the amount of memory to allocate for this task, however. I have the following prerequisites:

- All the memory must be non-virtual; i.e. I only want to use physical RAM (otherwise it sort of defeats the purpose)
- All the memory ideally would be contiguous (though I'm not sure if this is achievable?), for speed

I'd like to somehow figure out what the maximum amount I could ask for is without breaking those prerequisites. I won't necessarily use the whole amount, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: What OS you are targeting? Closest to "non-virutal" for Windows is [non-paged pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I'd be surprised if you can get sizable amount of it and conveniently use from C#. Note that if you need Windows code and fine with existing API than [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be easier option (memory management done by OS)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, Windows. So are memory mapped files always virtual then?

Comment: (first comment is somewhat wrong - ignore). I torgot about `VirtualXXX` functions. Actually you can request physical memory to be locked for memory region (is it good idea or not - your call). Function is [VirtualLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I personally will not try using it as understanding system-wide memory allocation is not something I know about or want to care.

Comment: Your concerns are probably overrated. *Even* if data is flushed to the disk, this type of transfer is faster than alternatives, as the memory is not copied during MMF transfer (the pages are just remapped). Now, non-paged pool is a valuable resource and it's a BAD idea to use it for application needs (non-paged pool is an oxygene for kernel-mode code).